# Crash when creating 10000 objects in Realm on Android

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, insert, realm

I'm pretty new to Android and Kotlin.

I have an app that does some calculation. I'm trying to do some performance testing. To do that, I want to create 10000 objects:

```
    Thread().run() {

        try {
            val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

            // Test endedSessions
            val sessions = realm.where<Session>().findAll()
            if (sessions.size < 10) {

                val numberOfSessions = 10000

                realm.beginTransaction()

                for (index in 0..numberOfSessions) {

                    if (index % 1000 == 999) { // added to test and understand when it's crashing
                        Timber.d("****** committing at ${index} sessions...")
                        realm.commitTransaction()
                        realm.beginTransaction()
                    }

                    val session = Session.newInstance(realm, false)

                    // Set Data
                    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    calendar.set(
                        (2017..2018).random(),
                        (0..11).random(),
                        (0..28).random(),
                        (0..23).random(),
                        (0..59).random()
                    )

                    val startDate = calendar.time
                    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (2..12).random())
                    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (0..59).random())
                    val endDate = calendar.time

                    session.startDate = startDate
                    session.endDate = endDate

                    session.result?.let { result ->
                        result.buyin = buyinList.random()
                        result.netResult = resultsList.random()
                    }

                }

                realm.commitTransaction()

            }

            realm.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }

    }
```

The issue is that after 5000 sessions on the emulator I'm getting the following error:

> I/art: Thread[3,tid=26297,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x9e560e00,peer=0x12cf79d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
>   A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x65726e59 in tid 26292 (alytics.android)
>   I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   Application terminated.

I'm unsure if this is the best practice for inserting a lot of objects into Realm.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `SIGSEGV` means memory violation. I guess your code uses too much RAM at some point with the loops. Anything relevant in `/data/anr/traces.txt`?

Comment: BTW, you're doing `commitTransaction()` outside of your big loop. This means the 10000 transactions all get loaded in memory until flushed. Might be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm unsure I'm looking at the correct traces file. I've used adb to look for it and the file always ends with ""sdcard" sysTid=1796". Also, my device file explorer doesn't contain the "anr" directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an ANR (Application Not Responding) crash due to blocking the main thread. The root cause is this line:

```
Thread().run() {
  // do work
}
```

This does not do what you think it does. This is initializing a `Thread`, and then executing a block of code with that `Thread` as the receiver. However, it's not actually starting the `Thread` -- your code is being executed on the UI thread instead.

Instead, you need to supply a `Runnable` to your thread and `.start` it:

```
Thread {
  // do your work in here
}.start() // this kicks off the thread and runs the block above asynchronously.
```

Alternative, just create an executor and submit your work:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit { 
  // do your work in here
}
```